# Automatic OTP verification lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-broadcastreceiver

I am working on verifying the OTP automatically. 
In the versions lower than lollipop, it is working perfectly
But it doesn't work in 5.0 and above
I tried the code from the tutorial.
Here is the code:

IncomingSMS.java

```
  public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null)
            {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj .length; i++)
                {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])                                                                                                    pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String senderNum = phoneNumber ;
                    String message = currentMessage .getDisplayMessageBody();
                    try
                    {
                        if (senderNum .equals("+917760882587"))
                        {
                            MainActivity Sms = new MainActivity();
                            Sms.recivedSms(message );
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){}

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static EditText OtpNumber;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OtpNumber= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }
    public void recivedSms(String message)
    {
        try
        {
            OtpNumber.setText(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone help why is it not working for lollipop and above devices?

Comment: "But in the version lower than lollipop, it is not working.", "...why is it not working for lollipop and above devices?" - Which versions is it not working in?

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry for that, I updated my question. It is not working for 5.0 and above.. working fine for lower than 5.0

Comment: What's your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: @MikeM. targetsdkversion is 22

Comment: OK, it's probably not a permissions issue then. You said it's not working in Lollipop and above. What's not working, exactly? Is the `onReceive()` method running? Is it just not updating `MainActivity`? Because `MainActivity Sms = new MainActivity(); Sms.recivedSms(message );` shouldn't work on any version

Comment: onReceive is notworking.. the Sms.receivedSms(message) is working in lower versions, I can set the text easily

Comment: Well, then I don't know what effect the Android version is having on your code, because that absolutely should not work on any version. Also, if you mean `onReceive()` is not getting called at all, that doesn't make any sense to me either, because your `targetSdkVersion` precludes the Marshmallow permissions problem, and as of KitKat, the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast cannot be aborted. If by "onReceive is notworking" you mean you're just not seeing the update, then you should try putting log prints in the Receiver to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code only :-

```
SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdusObj[i]);
```

Comment: it didn't work.. I have moto X play with android 6.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SmsMessage[] messages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
```